# Unresolved reference: GlideApp in activity written in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

In short my problem is that I can't use GlideApp (generated API) in an activity written in Kotlin.

Interesting enough that Android Studio sees the reference, i can open the generated GlideApp, there is code completion, but when I try to build it, then it fails with

> "Unresolved reference: GlideApp"

The glide module was implemented in java since most of the apps code is written in java.

Any idea?

Comment: you should show your code..

Comment: It is a simple GlideApp.with call with no error in Android Studio, just when I build the code

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Are using `kapt` instead of `annotationprocessor` in gradle file? 
[V4 Generated API support Kotlin](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2089)

Comment: No because the GlideModule implementation is in java. I understood if that is the case I need to use the java annotation processor

Comment: Soo Turns out I NEED to use kapt and it's not an option. Maybe I did not understand the documentation correctly. So if I use kapt for annotation processing even if the GlideModule is implemented in java it seems to work.

Comment: Yes.  If your project contains Java classes, kapt will also take care of them.

Answer (score 24):

For those like me who had used `kapt` as suggested by karandeep but still had the problem - you have to create an `AppGlideModule` implementation:

```
// AppGlideModule.kt
import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule

@GlideModule
class AppGlideModule : AppGlideModule()
```

After rebuilding the project `GlideApp` can be imported (generated code).

More at [this medium post](https://medium.com/@vlonjatgashi/using-glide-with-kotlin-5e345b557547)

Comment: where do you add those lines?

Comment: @johnrao07 those lines typically go into a Dagger2 module file, e.g `MyModule.kt`. If you want to brush up on Dagger2 modules/components, here's an article that might help: https://distillery.com/blog/dagger-2-how-to-understand-and-use-components-and-modules/

Answer (score 21):

whoever still facing issue after extending AppGlideModule and adding

> kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'

then don't forget to include

> apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

on top in app or module **build.gradle**

Comment: this worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 8):

You could use `Glide` instead of `GlideApp`.

```
Glide.with(context)
            .load(image)
            .apply(RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.image_placeholder))
            .into(imageView);
```

Comment: If you added @GlidedModule, you need to use GlideApp instead of Glide. So this answer is not good for all cases

Answer (score 7):

To add Glide app you need to add:

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
```

Then you can use

> Glide.with(..)

That code uses default Glide.
If you want to have customized Glide, you will need to add

for kotlin:

```
kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.9.0'
```

or for java:

```
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.9.0'
```

Once when you Sync the project, you need to add Glide module class in your project:

```
@GlideModule
public class CustomGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {
    @Override
    public void registerComponents(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Glide glide, @NonNull Registry registry) {
        //register some components
    }
}
```

Once when you rebuild the project, new class GlideApp will be autogenerated.
You can now use Glide with the following code:

> GlideApp.with(..)

Comment: `kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.9.0'` solved the problem for me

Comment: adding the implementation of the direct github repo did it for me. implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'

Answer (score -3):

Okay I also had the but after just importing glide it worked
import com.bumptech.glide.glide

Answer (score -3):

Use `Glide` instead of `GlideApp`.