# Unresolved reference: CustomTarget while using glide

Tags: kotlin, android-glide

I am using glide in my kotlin project i am getting the error "Unresolved reference: CustomTarget " . I would like to know how to fix this error.

My code is :

```
Glide.with(context)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(url)
            .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
                }

                override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {

                }

            })
```

What i tried is

1. Added the following code :

   ```
    import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule
    import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule

    @GlideModule
    class RequiredAppGlideModule : AppGlideModule()
   ```
2. Added the following in gradle

   implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.7.1'

   ```
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.6.1"

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.7.1'

    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.14.2'

    kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0"
   ```
3. File -> Invalidate caches ,Restart

Reference :

[get image from Firebase storage. GlideApp unresolved reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52140973/get-image-from-firebase-storage-glideapp-unresolved-reference)

[Unresolved reference: GlideApp in activity written in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48707410/unresolved-reference-glideapp-in-activity-written-in-kotlin)

[Glide cannot resolve asBitmap()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46199440/glide-cannot-resolve-asbitmap)

[How does one use glide to download an image into a bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27394016/how-does-one-use-glide-to-download-an-image-into-a-bitmap)

Comment: I cannot see where are you trying to set image. Where is imageview where you want to load image?

Comment: its inside onresourceready() Which is not mentioned in the above code (to simplify)

Comment: Which version of Glide you using?

Comment: my version is 4.7

Comment: @RahulR Your can update how you resolved the issue. It will be helpful in future for someone